# Pushdown Automata for the Language of Both Balanced Parentheses and Brackets

Tags: math

I need to figure out a pushdown automata for constructing strings of the language of both balanced parentheses and brackets, such as this ((([()))])()[]. It seems pretty easy to do for one type of parentheses; your stack consists of ( that you push when you see them, and then you pop one off for each ) you see. However, I'm having trouble figuring it out for the two types of parentheses. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is best suited for Computer Science SE!

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble because the language you described is not context free (try writing it's context free grammar, it's impossible), because the [Pumping Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) doesn't hold for it.

Intuitively, a PDA can only "remember" one number at all times, while your language requires "remembering" the number of `(` and the number of `[` previously seen.

---

There is a subset of your language that is CF, the language of nested and balanced brackets and parentheses.

The CF grammar:

`S ->  B | P | ε`

`B -> [B] | [P] | ε`

`P -> (B) | (P) | ε`

And the associated PDA:

when it sees `[`, pushes `b`

when it sees `(`, pushes `p`

when it sees `)`, if `p` is at the top of the stack it pops it, otherwise it rejects the word

when it sees `]`, if `b` is at the top of the stack it pops it, otherwise it rejects the word